# Getting a weird scrollbar when loading in content by using getelementbyid

Tags: scrollbar, getelementbyid

http://bartoosterveer.nl/stageverslag/

As you can see the first page that loads is completely responsive, when resizing the text pushes down the portfolio section without any problems.

However when clicking "leerdoelen" "over jkv" or "werkwijze" it gives me an instant scrollbar, or a scrollbar when resizing. I want it to look like the first page.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the object an element to embed your content. You can do it with jQuery if you must (http://api.jquery.com/load/).

But I would stay away from that altogether: if you add content this way to an element without using fixed dimensions, its parent might not be aware of the size of the content and will not be able to make it fit (hence the scrollbar on overflowing content).

I would suggest to keep using jQuery for transitions but keep all of the content on a single page. Much easier for you.